# How to allow `null` as default value in Yup schema, while still not allowing `null` to be submitted?

Tags: typescript, forms, validation, yup

I have this Yup-schema defined:

```
export const ExpectedIncomeSchema = object({
  newIncome: number()
    .required()
    .typeError()
    .min(0)
    .integer(),
  fromDate: date()
    .required()
    .typeError()
    .min(startOfToday()),
});

export type ExpectedIncomeValues = Asserts<typeof ExpectedIncomeSchema>;
```

I'm now trying to use this schema for validation in a `react-hook-form`, and ran into the issue that I'm not allowed to set the `defaultValues` to `null` or `""`. Kind of obvious, since Typescript says the only allowed types here are `number` and `Date`, but I don't want to default these values to a valid value like `0` or some randomly picked date. I want these fields to be initially *empty*.

```
const methods = useForm<ExpectedIncomeValues>({
  resolver: yupResolver(ExpectedIncomeSchema),
  defaultValues: {
    newIncome: null, // <-- only number allowed, so type error in both Typescript and validation
    fromDate: null, // <-- only Date allowed, so type error in both Typescript and validation
  },
);
```

How can make both Yup and Typescript happy here? I want the fields to be nullable when I setup the form, but *not* when after the schema has been validated.

Does Yup have something clever for this, or do I have to do something hacky like this?

```
export type Nullable<T> = {
  [P in keyof T]: T[P] | null;
};


export type ExpectedIncomeFormValues = Nullable<ExpectedIncomeValues>;
```

One issue with this though, is that the error message will be a "type error" message, not the "required" message that I'd want in this case.

Comment: these examples may help [e.g_1](https://react-hook-form.com/get-started#Applyvalidation), [e.g_2](https://codesandbox.io/s/69461015-yup-react-hook-form-value-type-error-message-displaying-instead-of-required-lux2c?file=/src/index.jsx). If not then can you create an example?

Comment: #1 doesn't use Yup (or any other schema solution) for validation, and #2 doesn't use `defaultValues` or Typescript. Updated post with `useForm` example from `react-hook-form`, although the issue isn't really specific to that. It's more a `yup` and Typescript related issue.

Comment: In the `type` tab of first example they are handling type error [here](https://react-hook-form.com/ts)

Comment: @Usama Those type errors have nothing to do with this one

Answer (score 3):

The following *seems* to work, but not sure if it's actually *correct*. I realized `yup` has *two* type-helpers, `TypeOf` and `Asserts`. By adding `.nullable(true)` to the schema, the first will allow `null`, while the second will not. Which is what I want.

```
const schema = object({
  newIncome: number()
    .required()
    .nullable(true)
    .min(0)
    .integer(),
  fromDate: date()
    .required()
    .nullable(true)
    .min(startOfToday()),
});


type ValuesWithNull =
  TypeOf<typeof ExpectedIncomeSchema>;

type ValuesWithoutNull =
  Asserts<typeof ExpectedIncomeSchema>;
```